# "install: missing destination file operand after `rootterminal'"

Tags: shell, root

When I open root terminal then it simply starts a normal terminal. I cannot access root terminal.

When I update my root terminal by the following command

```
sudo apt-get update && install rootterminal
```

I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
install: missing destination file operand after `rootterminal'
Try `install --help' for more information.
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5):

You are running the wrong command. The `&&` means "do whsat is on the left of `&&` and, **if that works**, then do what is on the right". In your example, the left command is:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This will read the [repositories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_repository) and update the list of software that you can install. The command on the right (after the `&&`) is:

```
install rootterminal
```

So, the system will try and execute [`install`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_install.htm) which will give an error because it needs at least two arguments.

Basically, you need to understand that `command1 && command2` is actually two separate and independent commands. What you wanted to do is

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install rootterminal
```

EDIT: I thought that `rootterminal` was a specific Kali package but it does not seem to exist (as @umläute points out). To run a command as `root` you can use any of these methods:

- Use `sudo` to run the command as root

  ```
  sudo command
  ```
- Use `sudo` to *become* root and then run the command:

  ```
  sudo -i
  ### You will be asked for your password
  command
  ```
- Use `su` to become root

  ```
  su
  ## You will be asked for root's password
  command
  ```

Answer (score 1):

(note that I'm answering this as if it was a Debian question; I don't know about the specifics of *kali*)

on Debian, there is no package named `rootterminal`. if there was the correct way to install it would be to run:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install rootterminal
```

(which differs from your command as it invokes `apt-get` two times, rather than calling the `install` program (which is a better `cp`)).

the so called *root terminal* is simply another (x-)terminal that runs a shell as `root` (and has a fancy colouring)

the easiest way to create a root terminal is to open a normal terminal, and type (as described [here](http://gr8idea.info/os/tutorials/linux/terminal.html)):

```
su
```

once his works, you can create a shortcut that runs (e.g.) `xterm -bg green -fg black -s su`

Answer (score 0):

I had this in a legacy project where I also tried to install a package with the install command of a pip egg.

```
lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands# install yolk
install: missing destination file operand after `yolk'
```

The `install` in the question was the one used by an egg of pip. This `install.py` is in its commands folder from where you can use the pip egg to install packages. The OP did not mean to use apt to install `rootterminal` since it is a python package. The `install` needs a destination file as a second parameter. I guess that in your case, you are not in an egg, but you use the install command of pip without saying that pip should be used. Use `pip install` instead.